# Как сделать двойное(тройное) отрицание на wpf или windows forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, как на картинке. Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку над выделенным элементом(или группой элементов) появлялся знак отрицания(двойное/тройное).
Если нельзя реализовать на данных языках, то может хоть какие-нибудь другие идеи есть..

Comment: А если разделить это условие на сетку?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону контролов для визуализации LATEX. Я попробовал  библиотеку WPF-Math, но она, похоже, не поддерживает `\overline`. Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8899204/6766879

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну, можно сделать, хотя намного менее удобно, чем в TeX'е. Вам придётся самостоятельно измерять символы и работать со свойствами шрифтов. Вот вам простой вариант: он не учитывает курсив и строчные буквы.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Тест" Height="350" Width="525"
        TextBlock.FontSize="15">
    <Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="Host"
              ClipToBounds="False">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Target"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Заведём маленький вспомогательный класс:

```
class LevelDescriptor
{
    public double Y;
    public List<(double from, double to)> Lines;
}
```

Наш код:

```
string text = "(X & Y) & (X & Y) & (X & Z)";
// описание линий
var lines = new List<List<(int from, int to)>>()
{
    new List<(int from, int to)>() { (1, 2), (15, 16), (25, 26) }, // уровень 1
    new List<(int from, int to)>() { (1, 6), (11, 16), (21, 26) }, // уровень 2
    new List<(int from, int to)>() { (0, 27) }, // уровень 3
};

// вертикальное расстояние между линиями
const double vgap = 4;
// разрешение вашего монитора. (если оно изменяется, например, у вас их несколько, то
// надо подписаться на его изменение)
var pixelsPerDip = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerDip;
// куда пишем
TextBlock tb = Target;
tb.Text = text;
// отбираем у текстбокса шрифт
var font = new Typeface(tb.FontFamily, tb.FontStyle, tb.FontWeight, tb.FontStretch);

// форматируем текст
FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
    text,
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    font,
    tb.FontSize,
    Brushes.Black, // конкретная кисть нам не важна, мы используем только геометрию
    pixelsPerDip);

// на какой высоте начинается большая буква?
double vstart = formattedText.Baseline - font.CapsHeight * tb.FontSize;

// описатели линий
List<LevelDescriptor> result = new List<LevelDescriptor>();
// текущая высота
double height = vstart;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    // получаем окружающие прямоугольники для всех подстрок
    var boundingBoxes = line.Select(d =>
          formattedText.BuildHighlightGeometry(new Point(), d.from, d.to - d.from).Bounds);
    height -= vgap;
    // запомнили высоту, и левую/правую границу для каждого отрезка
    result.Add(new LevelDescriptor()
    {
        Y = height,
        Lines = boundingBoxes.Select(bb => (from: bb.Left, to: bb.Right)).ToList()
    });
}

// теперь создаём линии
var brush = tb.Foreground; // цвет такой же, как и у строки
foreach (var level in result)
{
    foreach (var d in level.Lines)
        Host.Children.Add(
            new Line()
            {
                X1 = d.from, X2 = d.to,
                Y1 = level.Y, Y2 = level.Y,
                StrokeThickness = 1, // толщина
                Stroke = brush,
                Fill = brush
            });
}
```

Вот и всё. Вам придётся на основе своих данных самостоятельно строить таблицу `lines`.

У меня вышел вот такой результат:

[image: да, я знаю, что TeX круче, но WPF тоже кое-что может в умелых руках]

Comment: А не можете, пожалуйста, еще помочь: как поставить отрицание именно над выделенным текстом, например, по нажатию кнопки?
Если есть возможность, то покажите это кодом?

Comment: @Анастасия: А вот это уже сложнее. Если вам нужно отображать не в `TextBlock`'е, а в `TextBox`'е (выделить текст можно только там), мой код не подойдёт. Плюс, вам придётся получать индексы выделенных элементов (это просто), и проверять их на осмысленность, например, чтобы линия не заканчивалась посередине формулы (это сложно).

Comment: а другие варианты, где и как это реализовать существуют?

Comment: @Анастасия: Ну, хм. Смотря что вам нужно. Где именно вы собираетесь показывать текст? В `TextBox`'е? В `TextBlock`'е? Ещё где-нибудь?

Comment: Хочу в TextBox'е.

Comment: @Анастасия: Окей, тогда возникают такие вопросы: в TextBox’е можно вставить и/или удалить текст. Что при этом должно происходить с линиями? Вам придётся отслеживать положения символов, и перерисовывать линии. Если пользователь удалит часть текста, над которой линия, вам придётся сделать что-то разумное. И то же при копировании и вставке.

Comment: Но базовая проблема — как получить положение начала текста относительно `TextBox`’а. (Зная это смещение, вы сможете точно так же перерисовываться линии.) Это по идее стоит задать отдельным вопросом.